# Tez - DAGAppMaster - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ContainerId

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, tez, apache-tez

I try to launch a mapreduce job, but I get an error while excuting the jobs in shell or in hive :

> hive> select count(*) from employee ; Query ID =
>   mapr_20171107135114_a574713d-7d69-45e1-aa73-d4de07a3059b Total jobs =
>   1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks determined at
>   compile time: 1 In order to change the average load for a reducer (in
>   bytes): set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer= In order to
>   limit the maximum number of reducers: set
>   hive.exec.reducers.max= In order to set a constant number of
>   reducers: set mapreduce.job.reduces= Starting Job =
>   job_1510052734193_0005, Tracking URL =
>   http://hdpsrvpre2.intranet.darty.fr:8088/proxy/application_1510052734193_0005/
>   Kill Command = /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hadoop job -kill
>   job_1510052734193_0005 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of
>   mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0 2017-11-07 13:51:25,951 Stage-1 map
>   = 0%, reduce = 0% Ended **Job = job_1510052734193_0005 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information... **FAILED: Execution
>   Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask**
>   MapReduce Jobs Launched: Stage-Stage-1: MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0
>   FAIL Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 mse

in Ressourcemanager logs that what I find :

```
>     2017-11-07 13:51:25,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl:
> appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 State change from LAUNCHED to
> FINAL_SAVING 2017-11-07 13:51:25,269 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore:
> Updating info for attempt: appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 at:
> /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/system/FSRMStateRoot/RMAppRoot/application_1510052734193_0005/appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002
> 2017-11-07 13:51:25,283 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService:
> Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002
> 2017-11-07 13:51:25,283 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager:
> Application finished, removing password for
> appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 2017-11-07 13:51:25,283 **INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl:
> appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to
> FAILED** 2017-11-07 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: The
> number of failed attempts is 2. The max attempts is 2 2017-11-07
> 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl:
> Updating application application_1510052734193_0005 with final state:
> FAILED 2017-11-07 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl:
> application_1510052734193_0005 State change from ACCEPTED to
> FINAL_SAVING 2017-11-07 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore:
> Updating info for app: application_1510052734193_0005 2017-11-07
> 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler:
> Application appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 is done.
> finalState=FAILED 2017-11-07 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore:
> Updating info for app: application_1510052734193_0005 at:
> /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/system/FSRMStateRoot/RMAppRoot/application_1510052734193_0005/application_1510052734193_0005
> 2017-11-07 13:51:25,284 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo:
> Application application_1510052734193_0005 requests cleared 2017-11-07
> 13:51:25,296 INFO
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl:
> Application application_1510052734193_0005 failed 2 times due to AM
> Container for appattempt_1510052734193_0005_000002 exited with
> exitCode: 1 For more detailed output, check application tracking
> page:http://hdpsrvpre2.intranet.darty.fr:8088/cluster/app/application_1510052734193_0005Then,
> click on links to logs of each attempt. Diagnostics: Exception from
> container-launch. Container id:
> container_e10_1510052734193_0005_02_000001 Exit code: 1 Stack trace:
> ExitCodeException exitCode=1: at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545) at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456) at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:304)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:354)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:87)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Shell output: main : command
> provided 1 main : user is mapr main : requested yarn user is mapr
>     
>     Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1 Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Also , in sys log of jobs I find :

> 2017-11-07 12:09:46,419 **FATAL [main] app.DAGAppMaster: Error starting
>   DAGAppMaster java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ContainerId:
>   container_e10_1510052734193_0001_01_000001      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toContainerId(ConverterUtils.java:182)
>   at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.main(DAGAppMaster.java:1794)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException:** For input string: "e10"
>   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)      at
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toApplicationAttemptId(ConverterUtils.java:137)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toContainerId(ConverterUtils.java:177)
>   ... 1 more

It seems to be that Tez which causes the issue, is there any solution to solve that? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think that the execution environment has ***different versions*** of hadoop and their respective jar files.

Please verify the environment and make sure you use only the required version and remove the references of other versions from any of your environment variables.

Comment: Exactly ! Problem resolved after adapting library versions of Tez . 

Thank you :)